# Fixed columns not working - thead, tbody, tfoot

Tags: html, css

I found a nice "fixed table" style but not enough for what I'm looking for.
What I need is also freeze the second line (Header 1.x) and the last column (Header 8.1). I made some changes, td to th (following the first column sample), but not working.
Any ideas?

This is the code I have:

```css
 .table-scroll {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: auto;
      height: 350px;
    }
    
    .table-scroll table {
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 1280px;
      margin: auto;
      border-collapse: separate;
      border-spacing: 0;
    }
    
    .table-wrap { position: relative; }
    
    .table-scroll th, .table-scroll td {
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      background: #fff;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .table-scroll thead th {
      background: #333;
      color: #fff;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .table-scroll tfoot, .table-scroll tfoot th, .table-scroll tfoot td {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      bottom: 0;
      background: #666;
      color: #fff;
      z-index: 4;
    }
    
    th:first-child {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      background: #ccc;
    }
    
    thead th:first-child, tfoot th:first-child { z-index: 5;}
```

```html
 <div id="table-scroll" class="table-scroll">
      <table id="main-table" class="main-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Header 1</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 4</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 5</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 6</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 7</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 8</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Header 1.1</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 2.1</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 3.1</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 4.1</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 5.1</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 6.1</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 7.1</th>
            <th scope="col">Header 8.1</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Fixed left</th>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <th>Fixed right</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Fixed left</th>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <th>Fixed right</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Fixed left</th>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <th>Fixed right</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Fixed left</th>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <th>Fixed right</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Fixed left</th>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <th>Fixed right</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Fixed left</th>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <th>Fixed right</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Fixed left</th>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <th>Fixed right</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Fixed left</th>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <th>Fixed right</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Fixed left</th>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <th>Fixed right</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Fixed left</th>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <th>Fixed right</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Fixed left</th>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <th>Fixed right</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Fixed left</th>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <td>Cell content</td>
            <th>Fixed right</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Footer 1</th>
            <td>Footer 2</td>
            <td>Footer 3</td>
            <td>Footer 4</td>
            <td>Footer 5</td>
            <td>Footer 6</td>
            <td>Footer 7</td>
            <th>Footer 8</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wsr2ea9m/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**New answer:**

**TL;DR;**
Here is the working code on Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/vjmc52tf/
Here is the working code for Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/36yabef7/

To sum up your question, as I understand, I assume that you want your table to freeze:

1. The first column (you done it)
2. **The last column (not done yet)**
3. **2 first rows (hasn't worked as expected)**
4. The last row/footer (done)

As you've already done the **(1)** task, the **(2)** is basically the same, you just need to add `:last-child` selectors for those styles you've declared to freeze the first column, and add 1 more line `right: 0;`, the last column will also freeze as expected, here's the code:

```
th:first-child,
th:last-child { // add th:last-child
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  right: 0; // add right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #ccc;
}

thead th:first-child,
tfoot th:first-child,
thead th:last-child, // add thead th:last-child 
tfoot th:last-child { // add tfoot th:last-child
  z-index: 5;
}
```

To do the **(3)** task, notice that Edge and Chrome [have a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=702927) that currently `position: sticky` doesn't work on `thead` and `tr` elements, but it's possible to use it on `th` elements.

- So, to make it work on Firefox, it's more intuitive, just freeze the `thead` elements instead of `.table-scroll thead th`:

```
.table-scroll thead th {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;

  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

// become --------------------
.table-scroll thead th {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.table-scroll thead {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;

  z-index: 10; // need this to work correctly
}
```

- On Chrome it's trickier because of the bug, you have to manually freeze each cell `.table-scroll thead th` (like what you did), and then manually recalculate the `top` position of the cells for those're not in the first row:

```
.table-scroll thead th {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

// add this to make the second row work --------------------
.table-scroll tr:nth-child(2) th {
  top: 30px; 
}
```

Comment: many many many thanks for your help! I didnt know about Edge/Chrome bug.your explanation helped me to understand that.

Comment: @aa_sp You're welcome. I'm the one who has to say thank because actually I learned it along the way because of your question haha.